# Can't access webserver inside LAN

Tags: networking, iptables, firewall

I have tried apache and php's internal server, with none of them I can access from another computer if I use the internal IP. \

In the browser it sais "The connection has timed out. The server at 192.168.0.150 is taking too long to respond."

I have tried to ping the IP and it works, but that's the most I could do.

```
Pinging 192.168.0.150 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.0.150: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.150: bytes=32 time=9ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.150: bytes=32 time=19ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.150: bytes=32 time=31ms TTL=64

Ping statistics for 192.168.0.150:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 1ms, Maximum = 31ms, Average = 15ms
```

This is IPTables (have removed docker, but those entries are still present):

```
sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain DOCKER (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain DOCKER-USER (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

If I try `telnet 192.168.0.150 80` from my Windows PC I get "connection failed", so the port is not accessible.

I also tried `netstat` and got this:

```
netstat -ntulp | awk '/^Proto/ || /:80/'
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      515050/apache2
```

What else can I try to debug this?
From that PC I can access others, but the other way around I can't, only ping works.

Comment: You've got docker. What's the relevance of this to your Apache web server

Comment: if apache is running in a docker container, can you add details about that - you've probably *done something wrong™*

Comment: Can you telnet your apache webserver port from others PC? `telnet 192.168.0.150 80` because by default apache listen on port 80 or can you ssh to the apache server then find out is apache port listen on not. `netstat -ntulp | grep 80`

Comment: We need a network diagram showing all the routers / nat / subnets noting where the origin server is and where the browser client is.

Comment: @JaromandaX I don't use docker anymore, have removed it now for good.

Comment: @roaima Docker was installed for something else, not for apache, it's removed now.

Comment: @symcbean The network is pretty simple, haven't changed any hardware since it was already working. I have a router and connected to this router I have the laptop, which is the one hosting the webserver and a PC connected through cable, to the same router. As I said, it was working fine ~half a year ago, with the same hardware. That's the thing, I haven't changed anything, but it stopped working. From the laptop I can connect to the other PC, but not reverse.

Comment: Have tried to telnet from the Windows PC and I get connection failed. So the port is not accesible. Did ran the netstat with sudo and sais "tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      515050/apache2"

Comment: "_As I said, it was working fine_" - no, you haven't said that before. There is nothing in your question that says it used to work. Comments don't count - put _everything_ relevant into your question

Comment: @roaima Sorry, my bad, I posted in a lot of places, forgot what I said and where.

Comment: Looks like port 80 is only listening on IPv6 (as per netstat command output)

Comment: @BruceMalaudzi Have tried http://[::ffff:c0a8:96] on localhost and works, which means 192.168.0.150, but if I try on any other machine it doesn't, it also redirects to https://[::ffff:c0a8:96] fast, if I try 192.168.0.150 it takes a while until timedout but stays on http